# Android Studio WebView accessing external project files from javascript

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to access a file that is not in the assets folder from javascript using fetch().
The asset folder works for html,js,xml but does not seem to support other file types and besides I don't  want it to get cluttered.

However, I have not found the proper "https..." string that allows me to access external
files that are part of the project.

Any clues how to set up ?  Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can put all kind of files in assets folder.

Comment: Which files are you referring to?